# Arch Linux Installation medium no video signal after grub

Tags: arch-linux, system-installation, grub

## Problem summary

Hi! I've decided to finally switch my Windows to Arch. What I've done step by step:

1. I've created live USB with the latest official arch distro via rufus. The settings are on the attached screenshot [image]
2. I've booted to the live USB from UEFI
3. I get the basic grub with medium options, choose the default one.
4. After "triggering uevents" the screen turns black and monitor says it has no signal, but the PC continues to work, the keyboard led is on. [image]

## What I've tried:

1. Disabling CSM in UEFI;
2. Writing arch into usb with ISO and DD option;
3. Using another flash drive;
4. Disconnecting second monitor.

## Hardware info (ask if you need more):

1. Motherboard is asrock b550m pro-4 with latest bios (2022.03 non-beta);
2. Monitors are connected via DP.

P.S. I've already performed the installation of arch for tests last year, everything went fine. Can't really say what has changed, the only difference is that I had another monitor connected via HDMI.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem but different set up, I was trying to install arch on my old Pentium 4 with Nvidia GT 220. Maybe it'll work on your set up.

What I did was adding **nomodeset** to the kernel parameter, arch wiki has a page about it [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Kernel_parameters#systemd-boot).

Link that explaining [nomodeset](https://askubuntu.com/questions/207175/what-does-nomodeset-do) and this [reference](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=145857) or this [reference](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=271994) about this problem.